# How to substitute different number of digits behind special character with regex

Tags: python, regex

I have the following kind of string:`"§ 9,12,14,15 und 16"` or `"§ 9,12 und 16"`.

I want to change the string to:`"§ 9, § 12, § 14, § 15 und §16"` or `"§ 9, § 12 und § 16"`, respectively.

The number of digits varies and I want a code snipped that is applicable for all length:

```
text = "§§ 9,12,14,15 und 16"
text = re.sub(r'§* (\d+),(\d+),(\d+),(\d+) und (\d+)', r'§ \1, § \2, § \3, § \4 und § \5', text)
```

I only manage to match the string if I know the number of digits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no single regex which can do that. What you can do is split your string into parts, and perform a substitution on each.

```
text = "§§ 9,12,14,15 und 16"
parts = re.search(r'(§*)\s*((?:\d+,?\s*)+)\s*und\s+(\d+)', text)
if parts:
    sections = parts.group(2)
    text = re.sub(r'(\d+)', r'§\1', parts.group(2)) + ' und §' + parts.group(3)
```

The spacing in your example ends up being a bit irregular but this can be fixed up with some light post-processing.

```
text = re.sub(r',(?!\s)', ', ', re.sub('\s+', ' ', text))
```

Comment: thanks that's helps a lot. I only forgot in my example that I still have text at the beginning and at the end of the string that should remain unchanged: `"aaa §§ 9,16 and 15 bbb"`.

Comment: I solved it myself. I changed `parts = re.search(r'(.*)\s§*\s((?:\d+,?\s*)+)(\sund\s)*(\d+)\s(.*)', text)` and `text = re.sub(r'(\d+)', r' §\1', parts.group(1) + parts.group(2)) + ' und ' + parts.group(4) ' + parts.group(5)`

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by using `re.sub` with a regular expression and a lambda for replacements.

```
str = "aaa § 9,12,14,15 und 16 bbb"
rgx = r'(?:,|(?<!§) )(?=\d)'
```

```
re.sub(rgx, lambda m: ', § ' if m.group() == ',' else ' §', str)
  #=> "aaa § 9, § 12, § 14, § 15 und §16 bbb"
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/VWD18j/1)¯\*(ツ)*/¯[Python demo](https://tio.run/##FY5LCsMgAAX3nuI1GxUkYH@QUMlFulFi00BMRA200PvkHrmYNds3w/D8N72X@ZLz6PwSEoIlJKYAhUprjX1DI@RZyKuQN6xzD3mHMaYiYfgUKVDWteLHusdp3zg469Sz57Q0DmjruBpWTIFJO9NruBZUHFWK8QVXD2FZPeNQquwUdoq2oH0rUnnBCfFhnBOLnOT8Bw)

The regular expression can be broken down as follows.

```
(?:       # begin a non-capture group
  ,       # match a comma
  |       # or
  (?<!§)  # next character cannot be preceded by '§'
  [ ]     # match a space  
)         # end non-capture group
(?=\d)    # next character must be a digit
```

`(?<!§)` is a *negative lookbehind*; `(?=\d)` is a *positive lookahead*. I've placed the space in a character class (`[ ]`) merely to make it visible.